# Ubuntu Graphics Not Loading Properly even after fresh installation

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 in my workstation ( Dell T7500 ). I installed it successfully once but after recent problems and finally messing up while installing my Nvidia driver ( Nvdia Tesla C2050), i tried it re-installing. But even after repeated attempts, the installation doesn't load the graphics properly. I am attaching screen shots, one of login page, one of desktop and one of my icons. Hence I have following queries :

1) Why the GUI/Graphics is not loading properly even after fresh installation ? The problem is seen even before installation where the background and icons do not display properly why performing pre-installation selection and settings. I am trying ti install through USB. I tried by selecting "Try Ubuntu" option but that also has the same problem.

2) Recently I forgot my password so I went to the advanced recovery options and reset my password for root and user. But after upgrade of the Ubuntu software ( through Automatic Software Update), I was unable to login into and the login screen kept reappearing like a loop. I tried re-installing unity-desktop, lightdm, gdm and eventually nvidia driver but none helped and finally I had not option other that to re-install Ubuntu. From then this GUI/Graphics problem has started. So can you tell me the reason behind this login failure loop ?

3) When I install Nvidia driver through the "additional packages" manager then it used to install normally. But along with the current graphics display problem, the package doesn't install through it. Also when I tried to install Nvidia driver ( before and after this graphics display problem) while installing CUDA package following the instructions, the systems used to hang. Why so ? and can one provide one sure shot generic Nvidia driver installation steps for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

thanks in advance

[The screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oxhzycfbm7zf8gz/AABAzMlkfEHXFdnIyKbm65-2a?dl=0)