# graphics display at installation of 20.04.1

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, graphics, binutils

My question seems very similar to this question from someone five years ago: [Ubuntu Graphics Not Loading Properly even after fresh installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629306/ubuntu-graphics-not-loading-properly-even-after-fresh-installation)
Can someone give me a current solution to this problem for Ubuntu 20.04.1?
The latest Windows 10 update made my HP computer crash.  I did a factory reset to the original Windows 7.  I was able to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from an old DVD alongside Windows 7.  When I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.1, both from a DVD and from a Rufus USB stick, the graphic distortion began and I don't know how to straighten it out.  I really don't want Windows;  I want an up-to-date functional Ubuntu Desktop as my only OS.  What do I need to do?  thank you so much!

More information about the computer and the graphics card:
HP Pavilion Slimline Model #: s5503w, Software Build #: A1NAv6PrA8, Windows 7 64-bit, purchased in 2010.  I upgraded myself to Windows 10 in 2015 and installed a new graphics card at that time:  NVIDIA GEFORCE 309.08 DRIVER.
I have just re-installed Ubuntu 12.04, which is displaying normally, and the computer now says "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 96)"
The Disk has 316.7 GB and Memory has 2.7 GiB.

I opened DASH and clicked on TERMINAL, then entered the command:  
sudo lshw -C display
this is the output:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  sudo lshw -C display

*-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller

   product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]

   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
```

thank you so much for your patience and your good help!

I am in Ubuntu 20.04 in nomodeset !  Thank you for getting me this far!
I have installed updates that have recently been added.

I have downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137.run.
I have used the command chmod +x filename.run to make the run file executable.
I have used the command sudo ./filename.run to execute the run file.

The error message I am getting is:

ERROR: Unable to find the system utility `ld`; please
make sure you have the package 'binutils'
installed.  If you do have binutils installed,
then please check that `ld` is in your PATH.

I have looked on GOOGLE to find out how to do this, but none of the attempts I have made have worked.

Is anybody able and willing to point me in the right direction for this step?  thank you so much!

Comment: Please tell us more about the computer and the graphics card: Brand name and model of both. And let us also know the amount of RAM (GB). It will be easier to help you, when we know these data. Otherwise we can only guess what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the details :-) I think there is a problem for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS to find a suitable graphics driver for your nvidia card. When running Ubuntu 12.04, please run the following command line, and edit your original question to show the command and its output: `sudo lshw -C display`, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS might or might not work with a graphics driver similar (in version numbering) to the one that works with 12.04. It might also work with a newer proprietary nvidia driver, that you install manually (after booting with `nomodeset`).

Comment: The command is 'ell ess heitch double-u': `lshw`, so please try again with the command line in my second comment. You can copy and paste it from the comment into a terminal window.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that when you run Ubuntu 12.04, the graphics works, and `lshw` shows that the `nouveau` driver is used? That is the free driver for nvidia graphics, that is bundled with Ubuntu also in the current version 20.04.1. But of course it is a new version of the `nouveau` driver, that can identify and manage a lot of newer nvidia cards. It is sad that there is a regression for your card. If you get a boot menu at all, please try to add the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` or boot in recovery mode.

Comment: After installation of the current version of Ubuntu, it should be possible to install a proprietary nvidia driver, and it seems that `304` is the correct version (for Ubuntu). See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588538/whats-the-correct-driver-to-use-with-a-geforce-6150se-nforce-430-on-ubuntu-and).

Comment: It is strange that `sudo lshw -C display` does not work for you in 20.04.1. It works for me. Maybe some character was wrong, for example `-`.

Comment: But we know the graphics card model already, and you should test some suitable drivers, for example `304` according to the link in my previous comment. Please let us know if it works for you. Otherwise, you could search via nvidia's web page for a Linux driver with a number corresponding to that of the Windows driver that you reported in the original question, `309.08`, or with a number as close as possible to that. You could also test the current driver (the stable driver with the highest version number).

Comment: Reading [the whole link above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588538/whats-the-correct-driver-to-use-with-a-geforce-6150se-nforce-430-on-ubuntu-and) tells us that the original poster managed to use the nvidia driver `304`, but other users with the same model number of graphics card failed. Maybe the hardware in cards with that model number can vary. Let us hope that your card will work. Otherwise I have no solution for you (using Ubuntu 20.04.1).